# lock application with a lock a pattern

Tags: android

How can I make an activity which comes as a splash screen before the app starts and waits for a specific time like 3 seconds in which the user have to draw the unlocking pattern to get in to the application?

If the user is unable to draw the right pattern, the application should open a simple web browser or another activity which is not the part of the application.

Also, after putting in the correct locking pattern, how can a user change the locking pattern so that he can use the new pattern next time he uses the application?

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-lock-pattern/)

Answer (score 3):

Start by designing an activity that displays the splash screen. Then extend it with simple time-out logic that opens the web browser and calls `finish()` (to exit the splash screen activity). Then extend the activity (or perhaps the view showing the splash image) to capture user input and compare it to a pre-defined pattern. (I suspect that this is the core of your question. You will have to override onTouchEvent; capture the coordinates of ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, and ACTION_UP events; and compare the movement to your pre-defined pattern.) If the correct pattern is recognized, cancel the timer and start the new activity (with an Intent) and `finish()` the unlock activity.

To allow the user to change the locking pattern, you'll need to move the predefined pattern to the app's shared preferences or to some other modifiable location (such as data base or file). Then define an activity that prompts the user to define the pattern using whatever method you like (such as drawing the new pattern and capturing it using the same techniques as above) and which overwrites the stored pattern. Finally, rewrite your original splash screen activity to use the stored pattern instead of the predefined pattern (and, if the stored pattern isn't found, to initialize it with the predefined pattern).

Note that these two activities—unlocking the app and defining an unlock pattern—are separate from anything else in your app (except maybe a button or menu to let the user get to the pattern definition activity).

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use the Android Open Source Project's code:

http://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/source/browse/src/group/pals/android/lib/ui/lockpattern/widget/LockPatternUtils.java?r=7470bc287cba61198430e3d8aff32196bb5824a0